# How can I write this expression more compactly in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-8

How can I write that if more compact using java 8?

```
Optional.ofNullable(city).ifPresent(c -> {
    if (!city.equalsIgnoreCase(district)) {
        address.setCity(district + ", " + c);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'd replace `Optional.ofNullable(city).ifPresent(c -> {` with `if (city != null) {`.

Comment: and then it just becomes `if (city != null && !city.equalsIgnoreCase(district)) { ... }`, won't get more concise than that.

Comment: Yes, thank you for your comments. I wanted to do that, but my colleges use a lot of Optional, and I am quite new to lambda expression. I was just wandering if I can write that if in a more elegant manner.   I will use a simple if than.

Comment: `Optional` can be used to make null checking [more elegant](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/java8-optional.html), but it requires you design for it. You can't *force* it and hope it looks good, because it probably won't. You would need the elvis operator (see the link), and Java doesn't have it. It's possible that your colleagues are misusing `Optional`, if they use a lot of it. Ask them if they can explain the design behind their choices. If they can't, they might be a victim of [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Eran commented, you can avoid the spurious detour over `Optional` by just directly checking for `null`:

```
if (city != null && !district.equalsIgnoreCase(city)) {
  address.setCity(district + ", " + city);
}
```